# Display two html pages as one (xslt 1.0)

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have programmed two html pages with xml and xslt 1.0. I would like to display them after each other as one long html page. I use the function loadXMLDoc(filename) to transform my xml and xsl.

Page one: http://www.halfmen.dk/2016/teams/fks.htm
Page two: http://www.halfmen.dk/2016/teams/fks-fixtures.htm

Thank you in advance. McClaud

Sample Page:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadXMLDoc(filename) {
      if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }
      else {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
      try {
        xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"
      } catch (err) {
      }
      xhttp.send("");
      return xhttp.responseXML;
    }

    function displayResult() {
      xml = loadXMLDoc("fixtures.xml");
      xsl = loadXMLDoc("fks-fixtures.xsl");
      if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document") {
        ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
        document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = ex;
      }
      else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
        xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
        resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
        document.getElementById("input").appendChild(resultDocument);
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body class="animsition" onload="displayResult()">

<div id="input"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd highly recommend, that you switch to a server side XSLT transformation instead of doing the heavy lifting on the client.

Nonetheless you could chain the transformation and simply show both results after another:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadXMLDoc(filename) {
      if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }
      else {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
      try {
        xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"
      } catch (err) {
      }
      xhttp.send("");
      return xhttp.responseXML;
    }

    function displayResult() {
      render('opponents.xml', 'fks.xsl');
      render('fks.xml', 'fks-fixtures.xsl');
    }

    function render(xml, xsl) {
      xml = loadXMLDoc(xml);
      xsl = loadXMLDoc(xsl);
      if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document") {
        ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
        document.getElementById("input").innerHTML += ex;
      }
      else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
        xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
        resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
        document.getElementById("input").appendChild(resultDocument);
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body class="animsition" onload="displayResult();">

<div id="input"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Kevin Busse. I'm very happy with the result. Excellent.  :o)

Comment: ...It works like a charm in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Edge (updated versions) - but not in Explorer. In Explorer only the second transformation is shown. If it's very easy to adjust the client side script it will be appreciated - but only if it's simple. Thanks.  :o)

Comment: you missed the part where I wrote `document.getElementById("input").innerHTML += ex;` you'll need the `+=` operator to append, otherwise the second part only replaces the first

Comment: Just awesome, Kevin Busse. It works perfectly now.  ;o)